# Is there a directory my plugin can write files to that cannot be viewed via the browser/url?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, htaccess, directory

I want to restrict access to some files uploaded via the admin interface but I cannot rely on the ability to use `.htaccess` (could be turned off, or they might be using a non-apache web server). I cannot rely on having access to a folder outside the web root, so is there either a directory protected from viewing in wordpress or some way wordpress enables writing files that cannot be viewed publicly?

Comment: a solution could be changing the file format on the filename ! So file _example.jpg_ could be named as _example.zip_.

Comment: @Shazzad that will not stop anyone from viewing or downloading it.

Comment: That will prevent from viewing, but not from downloading :(

Comment: @Shazzad That's the same thing.

Comment: strictly speaking, the answer is no, but if you explain what you're trying to do, perhaps a workable solution can be offered.

Comment: @Milo I want to have files that the admin can upload and only logged in users can download them.

Comment: hash the filenames so they're not guessable, and serve them via php readfile.

Comment: @Milo hashing the file name is obscurity only, not full security.

Comment: well if you want zero additional requirements, it'll have to go in the database.

Comment: though depending on how sensitive the documents are, I think nesting them in randomized folder names and hashing the filename is sufficiently obscure. if it's really that sensitive, requiring server-level security is not unreasonable.

Comment: You can use the attachment.php template to serve the files, so you never reveal the actual location to the end users and you can use that to lock down access as needed. Require log in and then give them the file from an obfuscated url. Of course the original file is still accessible, but they would have to know where to look. This doesn't require changing the file name. The only way to fully stop access to the actual file would be to use htaccess to redirect users to a gateway file.

Comment: @Jake `.htaccess` was the only solution I could think of, but that's only for apache and only if it's allowed in the httpd.conf

Comment: Yeah. I am not sure what your plugin is, but when I have wanted to protect downloads, I have used the attachment template as the only method to serve the file, so that the original url is never viewed. When a user meets criteria that the attachment template tests, it serves the file at that url to the user directly. So that the best they can do is share the file they downloaded or try to share a link that will not serve the file unless the next user also meets the criteria. And you can create hashed urls for the attachment template also to obfuscate the process. The hashed url is its own pass.